Suma de algunos datos de filas
Tengo la siguiente tabla que ya tiene su tratamiento
Pregunta, ¿Cómo puedo obtener la suma de la columna total de solo el rango entre 400 - 549 en el colegio A y el colegio B ?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
